# Como filtrar listas anidadas de objetos 5 niveles

Tags: javascript, lambda

Estoy investigando como filtrar listas de objetos anidadas. Pero no soy capaz.... El objeto que intento filtrar es:

```js
var objList = [
  {
    "name": "Object0Name",
    "id": "Object0ID",
    "Object1List": [
      {
        "id": "Object1id_A1",
        "name": "Object1Name_A1",
        "Object2List": [
          {
            "id": 187,
            "name": "Object2Name_A1",
            "Object3List": [
              {
                "id": "mammal",
                "name": "mammal",
                "Object4List": [
                  {
                    "id_client": "rabbit",                   
                    "Currency": "EUR"  
                  },
                  {
                    "id_client": "cat",                    
                    "Currency": "EUR",
                  },
                  {
                    "id_client": "tiger",
                    "Currency": "EUR",                    
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "Object1id_B1",
        "name": "Object1Name_B1",
        "Object2List": [
          {
            "id": 189,
            "name": "Object2Name_B1",
            "Object3List": [
              {
                "id": "fish",
                "name": "fish",
                "Object4List": [
                  {
                    "id_client": "tiger shark",                   
                    "Currency": "EUR",
                    
                  },
                  {
                    "id_client": "tuna",
                    "currency": "GBP",                   
                  },
                  
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

var response= objList.filter(function(Object0List){
   return Object0List.Object1List.filter(function(Object1List){
    return  Object1List.Object2List.filter(function(Object2List){
     return  Object2List.Object3List.filter(function(Object3List){
      return  Object3List.Object4List.filter(function(Object4List){
       return Object4List.id_client.includes("tiger");

      });
     });
    });
   });
  });



var myJSON = JSON.stringify(response);
console.log('The animal is:');
console.log(myJSON);
```

Estoy recibiendo todos los objetos, por lo que elfiltrado no me esta funcionando.
La salida que me gustaria obtener es todos los clientes que contengan la palabra tiger:

```js
var objList = [
      {
        "name": "Object0Name",
        "id": "Object0ID",
        "Object1List": [
          {
            "id": "Object1id_A1",
            "name": "Object1Name_A1",
            "Object2List": [
              {
                "id": 187,
                "name": "Object2Name_A1",
                "Object3List": [
                  {
                    "id": "mammal",
                    "name": "mammal",
                    "Object4List": [                     
                      {
                        "id_client": "tiger",
                        "Currency": "EUR",                    
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "Object1id_B1",
            "name": "Object1Name_B1",
            "Object2List": [
              {
                "id": 189,
                "name": "Object2Name_B1",
                "Object3List": [
                  {
                    "id": "fish",
                    "name": "fish",
                    "Object4List": [
                      {
                        "id_client": "tiger shark",                   
                        "Currency": "EUR",
                        
                      }                      
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Estoy seguro que estoy utilizando mal la funciona filter, ¿Podria alguien proponerme un filtrado que funcione con filter o expresiones lambda? (sin utilizar recursividad por favor)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta solución. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112318/jquery-to-filter-multi-level-json

Comment: Hola Kiko_L, muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero no puedo usar jquery :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer el filtrado deberás usar la función [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) para iterar en la lista de objetos pero que en tu caso al ya saber el nombre de las listas simplemente accedo a ellas, no obstante te sugiero que si puedes cambiar el modelo de tus lista aun nombre mas genérico así seria mas fácil iterar en ellas y también  seria mejor para un buen mantenimiento a futuro.

```js
var objList = [{
  "name": "Object0Name",
  "id": "Object0ID",
  "Object1List": [{
      "id": "Object1id_A1",
      "name": "Object1Name_A1",
      "Object2List": [{
        "id": 187,
        "name": "Object2Name_A1",
        "Object3List": [{
          "id": "mammal",
          "name": "mammal",
          "Object4List": [{
            "id_client": "tiger",
            "Currency": "EUR",
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": "Object1id_B1",
      "name": "Object1Name_B1",
      "Object2List": [{
        "id": 189,
        "name": "Object2Name_B1",
        "Object3List": [{
          "id": "fish",
          "name": "fish",
          "Object4List": [{
            "id_client": "tiger shark",
            "Currency": "EUR",

          }]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}]

objList.forEach(function(object, indice, array) {

  object.Object1List.forEach(function(object, indice, array) {
  
    object.Object2List.forEach(function(object, indice, array) {

      object.Object3List.forEach(function(object, indice, array) {

        object.Object4List.forEach(function(object, indice, array) {
        
          if (object.id_client == "tiger")
            alert("Se encontro coincidencia")
            
        });
      });

    });

  });

});
```